# Vehicle detection (OpenCV). Arduino or Rasp Pi?

Tags: arduino, opencv

I am new to open cv, and I'm starting to do a project.

I want to use open cv for vehicle detection. I prefer using C++ language.
Should I go with Raspberry pi or Arduino ? And why(what are the advantages and disadvantages)?

If I go with raspberry pi, will I still be able(how hard is it) to let say put on some led ,xbee(or other device to allow to communicate with other rasp) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Raspberry Pi**. Definitely. Way more OpenCV support. Way more processing power. Way more versatile. 
I would REALLY recommend that you read up a bit more. Open CV is often used on Raspi's.

Check these out:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/tag/opencv/

As for switching on a LED, OF COURSE! Here's a simple example of using the GPIO:
https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/tux-crossing/gpio-examples-1-a-single-led/

I know this is not such a great answer, but I hope it helps to put you into the right direction at least.